# java.lang.NullPointerException: (ListFragment)

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent, android-listfragment

Got this issue on a ListFragment, I think it's adapter's fault, but can't figure out why this is happening:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
```

CODE which probably contains mistakes:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();

    ArrayList<String> history = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("HistoryList");
    ListView historyList = getListView();
    ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, history);
    historyList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
```

Fragment which launches History one:

```
public class PrimaryFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.primary_layout, null);
    }


    ArrayList<String> history = new ArrayList<String>();
    //START//

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("##.###");
        SharedPreferences mDefaultPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        Set<String> set = mDefaultPreferences.getStringSet("key", null);
        if(set != null){
            history = new ArrayList<String>(set);
        }
        TextView money = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textCool);
        String storedValue = mDefaultPreferences.getString("last known value", String.valueOf(0));
        money.setText(storedValue);

    }
```

+

```
public void history(View view){

    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), History.class);
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("HistoryList", history);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

Most relevant part of logcat:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
10-23 21:01:32.268 12036-12036/com.androidbelieve.drawerwithswipetabs E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:337)
10-23 21:01:32.268 12036-12036/com.androidbelieve.drawerwithswipetabs E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:491)
10-23 21:01:32.268 12036-12036/com.androidbelieve.drawerwithswipetabs E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.androidbelieve.drawerwithswipetabs.History.onActivityCreated(History.java:26)`

EDIT:

I think I'm starting to understand what the error is:

I'm populating a `ListFragment` with an `ArrayList` which got its value in another `Fragment`, the Primary one, but this `code` which was first used on an `Activities` based App, used a `Button` to pass those values to the other `Activity`.
But now these are both `fragments` and are in the same `ViewPager`, then I've no `Buttons` to launch the `History` Fragment, I just have to *swipe*. So my new question is:

**How do I pass that `ArrayString` value to the `History ListFragment` knowing I can't launch it through a `Button` but I do it with a *Swipe*?**
I've tried to study the `LifeCycle` but couldn't come up with anything, let me know what you'll figure out!

Comment: Without the full stack trace, it will be difficult for us to help you. However, you should confirm that `history` is not `null`, as that would explain your symptoms.

Comment: are you sure you are not using `setArguments` to pass the `List`?

Comment: Made some edits @CommonsWare

Comment: `ArrayList<String> history` is null

Comment: Why is that @Blackbelt ?

Comment: I don't know, if this is really important, but the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putStringArrayListExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29) say "Add extended data to the intent. *The name must include a package prefix*, for example the app com.android.contacts would use names like "com.android.contacts.ShowAll".

Comment: Can you check history for nullity after this?
`ArrayList<String> history = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("HistoryList");`

Answer (score 2):

You need a package prefix when using putStringArrayListExtra

> **public Intent putStringArrayListExtra** (String name, ArrayList value)
>
> Added in API level 1 Add extended data to the intent. The name must
>   include a package prefix, for example the app com.android.contacts
>   would use names like "com.android.contacts.ShowAll".
>
> Parameters name   The name of the extra data, with package prefix.
>   value The ArrayList data value.

[putStringArrayListExtra docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putStringArrayListExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Cjava.lang.String%3E))

You'll need to add the package name to the string you are using to store the array list extra with.

```
public void history(View view){
  Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), History.class);
  intent.putStringArrayListExtra("com.androidbelieve.drawerwithswipetabs.historylist", history);
  startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: No it won't launch: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference` @CoryRoy

Comment: Question Updated @CoryRoy

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Bundle's with your Intent and sticking the ArrayList in the Bundle via [`Bundle.putParcelableArrayList()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putParcelableArrayList(java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3C?%20extends%20android.os.Parcelable%3E)).

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), History.class);
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putParcelableArrayList("HistoryList", history);
// intent.putExtras(extras);
startActivity(intent, extras); // can put as above, or do this instead
```

+

```
Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
ArrayList<String> history = extras.getParcelableArrayList("HistoryList");
```

---

Since you are using a Fragment, you should be able do it this way. Or if you prefer not to deal with making a Bundle object in your Activity, you could do it from [within the Fragment](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Creating-and-Using-Fragments#fragment-with-arguments).

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putParcelableArrayList("HistoryList", history);
MyFragment frag = MyFragment.getInstance();
frag.setArguments(extras);
/* Fragment Transition code */
```

+

```
public class MyFragment {
    public MyFragment() { ... } 

    public MyFragment getInstance( ) { ... } 

    public void onCreate( ... ) {
        this.history = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public View onCreateView( ... ) {
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (args != null && args.containsKey("History")) {
            List<String> temp = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("History");
            this.history.addAll(temp);
            getListAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It says I ca't use that bundle inside a Fragment

Comment: Question Updated @cricket_007

Comment: Answer Updated @InssideYou

Comment: Thanks man gonna try,  by the way in the method before I got some errors that's why I couldn't make it

Comment: Alright, but what do I put inside those brackets instead of ... @cricket_007 ?

Comment: The onCreates should be self-explanatory since the IDE auto-generates those. I updated the second link in my post

Comment: Mh, getting some errors again, may I ask you wether you're available to move this discussion to chat? We may also use TeamViewer if needed @cricket_007

Comment: Yea, I'm usually free after 7pm Central.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93422/discussion-between-insside-you-and-cricket-007).